# how to pessimistic locking in yii framework?

Tags: mysql, yii, pessimistic-locking

how to pessimistic locking in yii? I searched in google, not saw any post about "how to pessimistic locking in yii". So I ask every one, who known, can show me.

Comment: you can always use transactions

Comment: Do you have example? how to setIsolationLevel() for transaction to "a resource is locked from the time it is first accessed in a transaction until the transaction is finished"